# Bash collation strength (capital chars vs small)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sort

I have a script which reads input and counts the char occurrence. It's based on an array:

```
parse_stream () {
    while read -n 1 char; do
        if [[ -n $char ]]; then
            ((count++))
            ((chars[\\$char]++))
        fi
    done
}
```

It prints a simple report reading the array:

```
print_results () {
    { for i in "${!chars[@]}"; do
        echo -e "$i" "\t"  ${chars["$i"]}
    done } | sort
}
```

The results I get keep alphabetical order, but with intermingled low and upper case letters:

```
0    3362
[    1
/    1213
:    1628
_    168
1    7282
*    2337
2    3922
+    24
3    2261
4    2042
.    508
5    1624
>    575
6    1879
-    7128
7    1345
8    1895
9    853
A    1
a    2610
b    578
c    1430
C    2
D    1
d    1179
E    2
e    3166
F    1
f    853
G    1
g    962
H    1
h    633
I    11
i    2955
j    254
k    1157
l    2619
M    13
m    1915
n    1590
O    1
o    10983
p    2127
P    3
Q    11
q    118
r    14003
S    1
s    2559
T    2
t    8165
u    1067
v    595
w    4556
X    4
x    7802
y    660
z    193
ź    48
```

One time, the upper case comes first, another time it's the lower case. Is there any way to fix this?

The numbers are in mess too... But this can get sorted with `sort` (sometimes... why?...). Ubuntu here, if that matters.

You can see the whole script [here](https://github.com/twomasz/charstat/blob/master/charstat).

#### UPDATE

I applied `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8 sort` to the function in the script. It's not that garbled now, but still occurs with low and uppercase.

```
0    3359
1    7281
2    3931
3    2258
4    2046
5    1624
6    1882
7    1346
8    1892
9    846
A    1         #upper
a    2607      #then lower
b    578
c    1430      #lower
C    2         #then upper
D    1

...etc...
```

My normal settings are different, but inherited by the subshell:

```
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
tomasz@tomasz-Latitude-E4200:~$ (echo $LANG)
en_US.UTF-8
```

Which puts the "normal" or previous behaviour of `sort` in a difficult light.

Anyhow, the upper and lower cases also stay garbled after I use the LANG definition explicitly in additional sorting, ie:

`ll /usr/bin | charstat | LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8 sort`

This again produces this sequence:

```
A    1
a    2607
b    578
c    1430
C    2
```

#### UPDATE

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: The script shown isn't complete -

Comment: Yes, and it was with a wrong snippet, sorry.

Comment: Please see the whole [here](https://github.com/twomasz/charstat/blob/master/charstat).

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't `bash`, the problem is `sort`.

Now `sort` is *locale* aware.

If you run the `locale` command then it might say something like `en_US` or similar (if you're in the US; other languages have other locales).  There may also be an encoding (`en_US.UTF8`).

Now locales also affect ordering.

Let's take a simple example:

```
$ x="a\nA\nc\nC\nb\nB\n"

$ echo -ne "$x" | LANG=C sort
A
B
C
a
b
c
```

That looks like just what we want.  But...

```
$ echo -ne "$x" | LANG=en_US sort
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

Uh oh!

`sort` isn't the only program that can change behaviour based on locale.

If you want traditional consistent behaviour across setups then you need to set `LANG` yourself.

This isn't unusual and your OS may already do this as part of its own scripting.

For example...

On RedHat/CentOS a lot of `/etc/rc.d/init.d` scripts do this; eg `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network` has

```
interfaces=$(ls ifcfg* | \
            LANG=C sed -e "$__sed_discard_ignored_files" \
                       -e '/\(ifcfg-lo$\|:\|ifcfg-.*-range\)/d' \
                       -e '/ifcfg-[A-Za-z0-9#\._-]\+$/ { s/^ifcfg-//g;s/[0-9]/ & /}' | \
            LANG=C sort -k 1,1 -k 2n | \
            LANG=C sed 's/ //')
```

On debian, `/etc/init.d/exim4` sets `LANG=C` at the beginning, as well as various programs in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: In many of the locale definitions, case is _folded_ which means that `a` and `A` are considered equivalent and either may come before/after the other.  `LANG=C` (or `LANG=POSIX` for that matter) retains traditional ASCII ordering.

Comment: And there is no way to _unfold_ it?

Comment: By setting a LANG entry that doesn't do it.  That's why those script fragments specify `C` :-)     Now you _can_ specify only collate ordering with `LC_COLLATE=C` - that'll leave all other aspects of the language untouched, but for `sort` the results would be equivalent.

Comment: `LANG=C` doesn't solve it. Letters p and c have lowercase first, unlike the rest in my test. `LC_COLLATE=C` puts all the uppercases A-Z before the lowercase a-z. Now way to have it consistently aAbBcC?